# No option to create a new Managed Path inside Office 365 SharePoint online 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, online, managed-path

I am working on an Office 365 SharePoint online 2013. Now when I wanted to create a new private site collection, inside the online SharePoint admin center, I did not find the option to create new managed path, as I use to get when creating a site collection inside SharePoint on-premise. So how do I create a new managed paths inside SharePoint online?

Comment: This is by design. Get used to not being able to do a lot of the things you did on prem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short: you can't.
By default only `sites` and `teams` are available and that's it. You can't add new one.
Checkout related question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/72049/office-365-sites-vs-teams-managed-path-when-creating-a-site-collection)

Comment: thanks for the reply ,, but inside the link u provided , someone mention the following sentence in his reply "_You must also be aware that it is recomanded to keep to < 20 per Web Application, so you need to balance carefully how new Managed Paths are created._".. so this gives an indication that we can create new managed paths inside SP online but it is recommended to keep them < 20 .. is this correct ?

Comment: no, you cannot create managed paths in SPO.

Comment: @EricAlexander so we can only create new site collections either under "/teams/" or "/sites/" ??? which are both wildcard managed paths ?

Comment: True. In the related question Marius talking about on-premise managed paths, not online.

Answer (score 6):

It is not feasible. Every site should be created under https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites or https://contoso.sharepoint.com/teams.

Refer to: new-sposite. For your convenience, check the following screenshot.

[image]

[Read the answer here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_manage/create-custom-managed-path-for-a-site-collection/893dbeb1-83f2-4486-9598-baffc3628b71)

[Also read this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2014/09/01/sharepoint-online-information-architecture-considerations/)

Comment: this is a bit strange ,, so we only have two wildcard managed paths inside SP online "/sites/" & "/teams/" so we cannot even have an explicit including managed path ???

Comment: Yes, we cannot. This is another limitation